# WPF: How to split Listview columns into sub-columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, split, multiple-columns

I am new to WPF. I'm trying to make a `Listview` table. I want to split some of the columns. For example:

```
   parent column1      |        parent column2   
column1.1 | column 1.2 | column2.1 | column 2.2 |column 2.3
```

I've found a similar question here: [WPF: Spilt GridView header into two rows where the bottom row is seperated into two colums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313889/wpf-spilt-gridview-header-into-two-rows-where-the-bottom-row-is-seperated-into) 
but the answer there didn't work for me. I couldn't comment and ask for further explanation since I don't have enough reputation to comment. When I do the same thing, in my case, columns are showed okay but they act as one column. Child columns do not work. 
Here is my code sample:

```
<ListView Margin="20" Name="purchaseSummaryList" ItemsSource="{Binding purchaseSummaryCol, Mode=Default}"> 
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>
        //single example that works fine
        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id, Mode=Default}" /> //single example that works
        //parent column that acts as one column
        <GridViewColumn Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding pay, Mode=Default}">
          <GridViewColumnHeader>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
              <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" ShowGridLines="False" Width="300">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="PARENT"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Text="Child1" />
                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Text="Child2"/>
                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Text="Child3"/>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </GridViewColumnHeader>
        </GridViewColumn>
      <GridView.Columns>
    <GridView>
  <ListView.View>
<ListView>
```

I know that it's obvious that there is only one column which is parent one since I didn't bind anything to child columns. But the problem is, I can not. It doesn't allow me to use `DisplayMemberBinding` for child `TextBlock`. I also can not add new `GridViewColumn` inside `Grid`. I don't know how to model this.

Can someone help me with this problem? I would appreciate a good WPF tutorial link too where can I study. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this maybe what you're searching for?

```
ListViewItem parent1 = new ListViewItem("Parent1");
parent1.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");
parent1.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");
parent1.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");

ListViewItem parent2 = new ListViewItem("Parent2");
parent2.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");
parent2.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");
parent2.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");

ListViewItem parent3 = new ListViewItem("Parent3");
parent3.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");
parent3.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");
parent3.SubItems.Add("ChildItem");

ListViewXY.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {parent1 ,parent2 ,parent3 });
```

Comment: `ListViewItem` acts as items in veritcal list , right? Can I use them as columns? As far as I understand this would show me a tree list. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, this should show you a tree list. Columns would be ListViewXY.Columns.Add(text, width, alignment);

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe this one can be helpful: http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-listview.htm

Answer (score 1):

It require some more work, especially regardings the bindings of the values that i didn't tried, but this is working for the headers:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PurchaseSummaryCol}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>                    
            <GridViewColumn Header="PARENT" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pay}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MultiColumnHeaderTemplate}"
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource MultiColumnCellTemplate}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Then you need to have the resources for both header and cell template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MultiColumnHeaderTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            >RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Columns="{StaticResource SubColumnCollection}"/>      
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MultiColumnCellTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Columns="{DynamicResource SubColumnCollection}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now only defining the sub-list collection is left:

```
<GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="SubColumnCollection">
    <GridViewColumn Header="Child1" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Child1}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Child2" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Child2}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Child3" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Child3}"/>
</GridViewColumnCollection>
```

I didn't investigate but the binding of the children is not showing, other than that it works.

PS: Microsoft advice is using CamelCasing for properties.

Comment: Thanks mate now there are three columns as you said. But they still do act like one. I guess, I shouldn't bind anything to parent column, because it uses that binding as one column. Also I guess, I should somehow make a connection between subcolumns and parents about binding.